# Difference in meaning between "I provide her with a TV" and "I provide her a TV"?

Tags: meaning

What is the exact difference in meaning between "I provide her with  a TV" and "I provide her a TV" ?

Does "I provide her with a TV" mean "I own a TV. And I give her my own tv." ?
Does "I provide her a TV" mean "I do not own a TV. Nevertheless, I give her a tv in any way." ?

What does "with" mean in the sentence?
If we don't use with in the sentence, is there a difference in nuance?

Answer (score 8):

The expression is *provide [someone] **with** [something].* It says nothing about whether that thing is the provider's own, though if that were so, *I give her my TV* would be a more natural way of saying it.

*I provide her a TV* is not idiomatic English. We can say *I provide a TV for her.*

Comment: If so, what is the difference in use between "I give her a TV" and "I provide her with a TV" ? What does "I give her with a TV" mean?

Comment: @user22046 providing someone with something leaves the time period open - when you lend someone an object, you are providing it for a period of time. When you give someone an object, you are providing it forever (in theory!).

Comment: If so, if there is no difference of time period, I think that give and provide could actually be used in a similar way. By the way, why, the give does not have the with, but the provide have the with? I am really curious what that with means.

Comment: Does "I provide her with a TV" mean "I provide that she have a TV" ? does "with" mean "have" ?

Comment: If a person were, say, narrating their actions in the present tense, I think "I provide her a TV" would be reasonable to say. Example: "The new employee arrives. I provide her a desk and a computer." In the past tense, it sounds more reasonable: "The new employee arrived. I provided her a desk and a computer."

Comment: _"'I provide her a TV' is not idiomatic English"_ I don't agree. Could be cultural. But probably not as you're only a few miles away :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings _Provide [someone]_ is usually followed by _with_ when referring to the thing provided. See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/provide

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, usually, but omitting the _with_ is not unidiomatic. You can't get that from a dictionary; we call these things "facts on the ground". :) It's okay if you always use the "with" personally.

Comment: @CalvT If I provide 3 meals a day, I don't expect them to be returned to me...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings See https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-prepositions-provide/2701412.html

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm not disputing the fundamentals of grammar, nor do I need a lesson in them from some website. I'm telling you what people I know actually say in real life. That's what idioms are. So, no, this is not unidiomatic.

Comment: *I provide her a TV* is just as idiomatic as *I provide her with a TV*.  Both share the same problem that they're using the wrong tense, in the case of a TV, but they are both perfectly idiomatic otherwise.

Comment: If so(=I provide her a TV is just as idiomatic as I provide her with a TV.), does the "with" in the sentence have no meanng?

Comment: It doesn't change anything in the second sentence.  You could say it's implied in the first sentence though.  The second sentence is just the longer version.  It's like the difference between the sentences *Get some groceries.* and *You, get some groceries.* (bothe of which are imperative sentences with the same meaning).

Comment: I maintain that _with_ is required in the construction _provide [somebody] with [something]._ Others claim that it's acceptable to leave out the _with_ because some speakers do so.

Answer (score 5):

Let's examine the sentence structure of both:

I `[noun]` provide `[verb]` her `[direct object]` with a TV `[prepositional adverb]` .

I `[noun]` provide `[verb]` her `[direct object]` a TV `[indirect object]` .

Both of these sentences convey the EXACT same information. The `noun`, `verb`, `direct object` are the same, and it is up to the speaker on how to convey the remainder - as either a `prepositional adverb` or a `indirect object`, which is just a difference in grammar and has no underlying importance in this example.

Neither sentence delivers any information about who owns the TV.

Comment: You swapped the direct and indirect objects in your second example. (And the first example, her is still also an indirect object)

Answer (score 1):

You can also say:
"I provide TV for her"

or:
"TV, her I provide"

It all depends on how much of a robot do you want to sound like. Or it can also depend on how much like a robot you want to sound.

Answer (score 0):

I provide her with a TV, because a TV is a tangible object.
I provide for her - no tangible object; support is real but not an object
I provide perspective - same as above, nothing tangible

Comment: You could also say "I provide a TV for her"